# localhost eclipse 404 tomcat 8

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I just installed Eclipse and Tomcat 8 to work on a shared project, that I got from bitbucket/sourcetree.

But when I add the project to the Tomcat 8 server, I get 404 status.

I tried creating a new dynamic web project and made a test.html in WebContent, added it to the server and it worked.

What can be the reason that one projects works in my server, but the other one does not?

Comment: Did you deploy the projects the same way? Did you check the Url is correct (@see servlet mapping; projectname != context name)? And so on...

Comment: Please add more details - like what were the url, what is the folder structure, etc

Answer (score 0):

Check the shared project Targeted Runtimes. It could be set to another version of Tomcat.

Project -> Properties-> Targeted Runtimes